# Put Data in mutlple branch of Array : Json Transformer ,Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, transformation

i want to add values to all the arrays in json object.

For eg:

value array [4,2.5,2.5,1.5]
json =

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one",
      "price": {}
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "three",
      "price": {}
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "four",
      "price": {
        "value": 1.5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to transform the above json in

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one",
      "price": {
        "value": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two",
      "price": {
        "value": 2.5
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "three",
      "price": {
        "value": 2.5
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "four",
      "price": {
        "value": 1.5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how do i achieve this. My goal is to put values inside the specific fields of json array. I am using play json library throughout my application. What other options do i have instead of using json transformers.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You may use simple transformation like

```
val prices = List[Double](4,2.5,2.5,1.5).map(price => Json.obj("price" -> Json.obj("value" -> price)))

val t = (__ \ "items").json.update(
  of[List[JsObject]]
    .map(_.zip(prices).map(o => _._1 ++ _._2))
    .map(JsArray)
)

res5: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"items":[{"id":1,"name":"one","price":{"value":4}},{"id":2,"name":"two","price":{"value":2.5}},{"id":3,"name":"three","price":{"value":2.5}},{"id":4,"name":"four","price":{"value":1.5}}]},/items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using classes, but not sure this fits to your project because it's hard to guess how your whole codes look like.
I put `new Item` manually for simplicity. You can create `items` using Json library :)

```
class Price(val value:Double) {
    override def toString = s"{value:${value}}"
}

class Item(val id: Int, val name: String, val price: Price) {
    def this(id: Int, name: String) {
      this(id, name, null)
    }

    override def toString = s"{id:${id}, name:${name}, price:${price}}"
}

val price = Array(4, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5)

/** You might convert Json data to List[Item] using Json library instead. */
val items: List[Item] = List(
    new Item(1, "one"),
    new Item(2, "two"),
    new Item(3, "three"),
    new Item(4, "four", new Price(1.5))
)

val valueMappedItems = items.zipWithIndex.map{case (item, index) =>
    if (item.price == null) {
      new Item(item.id, item.name, new Price(price(index)))
    } else {
      item
    }
}
```

Comment: why create extra classes only in order to modify the json object?

Comment: @andrey.ladniy I think it represents json object in clearer way, and easy to use after modification

Comment: we don't know the purpose of conversion to say that it will be easier (originally, the task is simply to transorm Json). If later is the Json response, then converting it into additional classes and backward it's just more overhead. coast-to-coast design is difficult to understand at first, but then its use simplifies and speeds up application and development.

Comment: @andrey.ladniy agreed. Thanks for your opinion :)